# jQuery event handlers added via each() seem to overwrite earlier ones

Tags: javascript, jquery, closures

This is my very first time using jquery and I don't understand the following 'side-effect':

script.js:

```
$(function() {
  $("button").each(function() { 
    $t=$(this);                 
    $t.on("click", function() {
      console.log("Id: " + $t.attr('id'));
    });
  });
});
```

html:

```
...
<body>
  <button id="de">de</button>
  <button id="en">en</button>
</body>
```

When I click the "de" button and then the "en" button the log gives me:

```
en
en
```

It seems to be an effect of overwriting the listener function in the second call, is that right? How do I avoid this?

Comment: The log gives you that when you do what? You've attached click handlers - what did you click?

Comment: I clicked each of the the buttons. First "de" followed by "en"...

Comment: This is a closure-related bug, but the code on display doesn't look like it has one. Are you 100% certain that the code you posted is identical to that which runs?

Comment: @DudeSolutions: [No it won't](http://jsfiddle.net/YVvX8/). Why would it?

Comment: I updated my question. Of course I made a variable for this but I thought this would be without any impact. That's why I pasted one part of my code. This was a mistake. Won't do that again. The problem is the variable

Comment: uff ... but feel free to explain me what happens there. I'm still wondering

Comment: @JohnRumpel: Finished writing an explanation, hope that helps.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**After the update**

In your updated question `$t` is a **global** variable. In JavaScript (usually) everything you declare without putting `var` in advance is a global variable bound to window (in the browser).

You can fix your code by changing `$t = ...` to `var $t = ...` which would declare `$t` in the handler

---

jQuery lets you attach click handlers to multiple buttons without using `.each` to iterate through them.

Your code is supposed to work , but might be problematic if you're invoking the handler in a way that might change `this` (note, you can close over `this` (or use bind) in the `.each` in your code to make sure you're getting the same `this`, you can also try logging `$(this).attr('id')` in the each)

Try:

```
$(function(){
  $("button").click(function() {                     
      console.log("Id: " + $(this).attr('id'));
  });
});
```

[**Here is a working fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/cHMeg/)

[(Your original code works too by the way (fiddle))](http://jsfiddle.net/KJJT4/)

In handlers jQuery returns the actual dom element which you wrap in `$()` to make a jQuery object again. You don't need to construct a jQuery object just to get the ID, `$(this).attr('id')` can be replaced with `this.id` .

Comment: You are absolutely right. I made a variable as suggested in my tutorial. But I didn't saw that there is any kind of impact there...

Comment: @JohnRumpel I'm glad I could help, if this answer has resolved your issue please consider accepting it.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: Unfortunately, the first part is incorrect: `var $t` won't fix it.

Comment: @Jon Sure it will, `$t` will be closed under the `$.each` ... that's how closures work. Here http://jsfiddle.net/WdFR3/

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: Wow. I think I mentally read `.each` as a plain loop. Dumb moment, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

### The problem: closure

Your code has a closure-related bug introduced by the presence of `$t`. What happens is that a click handler is installed on every button; all of those click handlers refer to the button as `$t`. This means that a reference to `$t` is taken when the handler is installed and evaluated *when the handler is invoked*.

It should be easy to see where this is going: when *any* handler is invoked the loop has already completed, so `$t` has the value of the last button iterated upon. In effect every button has a handler that operates as if the last button were clicked.

### How to solve it

One way is to avoid creating a closure in the first place:

```
$(function() {
  $("button").each(function() { 
    $(this).on("click", function() {
      console.log("Id: " + $(this).attr('id'));
    });
  });
});
```

No `$t`, no problem. You could actually write this equivalently as

```
$(function() {
  $("button").on("click", function() {
    console.log("Id: " + $(this).attr('id'));
  });
});
```

Otherwise, you need to make sure that `$t` is *a different `$t` on each loop iteration*. The way to do that is by limiting the scope of `$t` to the loop body. Since JavaScript has function scope, the only way to do so is by introducing and calling a function on the spot:

```
$(function() {
  $("button").each(function() { 
    var $t=$(this);
    (function($u) {
      $u.on("click", function() {
        console.log("Id: " + $u.attr('id'));
      });
    })($t);
  });
});
```

In this version each handler is actually dependent on `$u`, which in turn is not shared among handlers. This solves the closure problem.

Note that I could have named the innermost function argument `$t` as well (in which case the name would have hidden the `$t` from the iteration scope); I chose not to do that only for clarity.

Comment: If you could fix the global ( `$t` )in your last code example, I'll gladly give you that +1 back :)

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: Ah yes. Copy/pasting from the question, sorry. :-)